# Vectorizing the product of a difftime

Tags: r, date

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    ID Initialdate  Finaldate
  1405  2003-12-03 2010-12-07
  7044  2004-12-08 2011-10-13
  7219  2008-05-16 2009-06-04
 18618  2004-06-17 2012-02-13
 19900  2005-06-01 2008-06-11
 20138  2010-01-20 2010-01-20
 29067  2003-04-30 2004-09-10
 33546  2003-11-25 2008-10-10
 37321  2003-06-07 2006-03-20
 43028  2004-09-23 2008-07-25
 43591  2005-04-06 2005-11-15
 46749  2005-02-28 2005-05-16
 48846  2005-08-02 2005-08-02
114353  2002-05-17 2006-10-26
128180  2004-06-17 2010-06-21
128648  2003-05-07 2009-07-23
133337  2004-05-26 2012-07-26
149181  2002-10-19 2008-07-27
214079  2003-09-26 2007-05-20
215060  2006-04-17 2011-08-17
229816  2007-04-25 2011-09-24
238123  2007-11-26 2012-01-31
253776  2006-03-02 2012-04-19
258660  2010-03-25 2012-04-09
265356  2002-04-22 2002-04-22
```

I made a fourth column containing the difference between the Final date and the initial date with the following code, and cleaned it as such:

```
df$Duration<-(difftime(df$Finaldate, df$Initialdate, units = "days"))
df$Duration<-as.numeric(df$Duration, units = "days")
```

I get the following output, which makes me happy:

```
    ID Initialdate  Finaldate   Duration
  1405  2003-12-03 2010-12-07 2561.00000
  7044  2004-12-08 2011-10-13 2499.95833
  7219  2008-05-16 2009-06-04  384.00000
 18618  2004-06-17 2012-02-13 2797.04167
 19900  2005-06-01 2008-06-11 1106.00000
 20138  2010-01-20 2010-01-20    0.00000
 29067  2003-04-30 2004-09-10  499.00000
 33546  2003-11-25 2008-10-10 1780.95833
 37321  2003-06-07 2006-03-20 1017.04167
 43028  2004-09-23 2008-07-25 1401.00000
 43591  2005-04-06 2005-11-15  223.04167
 46749  2005-02-28 2005-05-16   76.95833
 48846  2005-08-02 2005-08-02    0.00000
114353  2002-05-17 2006-10-26 1623.00000
128180  2004-06-17 2010-06-21 2195.00000
128648  2003-05-07 2009-07-23 2269.00000
133337  2004-05-26 2012-07-26 2983.00000
149181  2002-10-19 2008-07-27 2108.00000
214079  2003-09-26 2007-05-20 1332.00000
215060  2006-04-17 2011-08-17 1948.00000
229816  2007-04-25 2011-09-24 1613.00000
238123  2007-11-26 2012-01-31 1527.00000
253776  2006-03-02 2012-04-19 2239.95833
258660  2010-03-25 2012-04-09  746.00000
265356  2002-04-22 2002-04-22    0.00000
```

my plan from here was to vectorize the duration data, specifically those less than 180 days, then use that new dataframe to remove those ID#s from the initial dataframe using code like this: `df_final<-df[!(df$ID %in% unqualified$ID),]`. However, when I do it like this:

```
unqualified<-(df[df$Duration <= '179.000',])
```

I get this output, which is definitely not correct:

```
    ID Initialdate  Finaldate Duration
 19900  2005-06-01 2008-06-11 1106.000
 20138  2010-01-20 2010-01-20    0.000
 33546  2003-11-25 2008-10-10 1780.958
 37321  2003-06-07 2006-03-20 1017.042
 43028  2004-09-23 2008-07-25 1401.000
 48846  2005-08-02 2005-08-02    0.000
114353  2002-05-17 2006-10-26 1623.000
214079  2003-09-26 2007-05-20 1332.000
229816  2007-04-25 2011-09-24 1613.000
238123  2007-11-26 2012-01-31 1527.000
265356  2002-04-22 2002-04-22    0.000
```

I thought perhaps it was because there was an issue with the numbers in duration, but they are listed as numeric when i run `sapply(unqualified, class)` and `sapply(unqualified, mode)`. I should also mention that earlier in my coding I did convert the dates using strptime to make sure they were correct. I've searched around to try and figure out with the problem is but everything is coming up Millhouse... any help would be appreciated

Comment: remove quotes in your comparison, i.e. `df$Duration <= 179`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this:

```
unqualified<-(df[df$Duration < 180,])
```

I.e. your number as a number, instead of a string.

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid, that was easy. Thanks for answering the noob question!